# Dividing SELECT result to no block html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a MYSQL query SELECT that extract ~ 7000 rows and a HTML page print this results, so you can select a single result to work with.
E.g.:

```
NAME     SURNAME     
John     Woo         <a href="/select.php?id=3">Select</a>
Dary     Ext         <a href="/select.php?id=4">Select</a>
```

and so on.

But they are about 7000 results and PHP page uses several seconds to display all results. For several reason i cannot divide in multiple pages, but i saw in some site that in this case they are ready to show page immediately and after some second script adds other results in bottom... without jquery.

So, page starts, you see 100-200-300 results, page are loading (you could see the circle on firefox tab of loading) and moving on bottom wheel mouse, after some seconds you see that other records are displaied.

In my page instead you see page only after that 7000 results are loaded.

Could you please address me on correct way? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about infinite scroll loading. Well, your question is more JS than anything else. Please check out this [guide here](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) or this [other one](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/) how you can implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple just add a [`ob_implicit_flush();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) in the top of your script. This will make php send output as soon as it can without an explicit call to `flush()`.

The best solution, anyway, is to use ajax requests to load everything in blocks because with the auto-flush you won't send all the html content below the results of your query.

Answer (score 0):

its better to use some jquery plugins to manage data.  Use [jqgrid](http://jqgrid.com/) for it. It is best to have long listings. Quite easy to configure and use. Check [demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)